# Tag wiki excerpts starting with different case

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Editing some of the tag wikis I was wondering, if there is or should be a consistent way for writing concerning the starting of the tag excerpt.

Some tag excerpts start as if the excerpt were to be read with the tag name as the start, i.e.:

[website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) `...involves the structure of the website including the Information Architecture, Layout, Content, and the conceptual design with branding.`

while others are written as complete sentences, i.e.:

[user-interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction) `User interaction is generally what happens when a user interacts with an artifact. How the users thinks and experience the interaction is what is placed on this tag.`

Is there a guideline as to which is the preferable style of formulating the tag wiki excerpt?

Comment: Thanx for this question @kontur, I'm sorry for the mistake mentioned above. I'll correct them when I find them :-)

Comment: Well, from a rough look at it, *about half or so of all excerpts* on http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags seem to be in the style in my first example - that's what initially caused my question and unsure take on what actually is the desired way of writting them. Should all of those, over time, get corrected?

Comment: I see no other choice than to make them correct. We just need to happily edit them, but maybe ask mods first,

Comment: What do you think of this @BenBrocka ?

Answer (score 2):

Wiki excerpts appear in many different contexts, so they should be written in complete prose so to stand on their own without the tag-prefix you quoted above.

See this tag wiki excerpt on Stack Overflow, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java